# SSDT schema compare, removing and then renaming stored procedure result is incorrect

Tags: ssdt, visual-studio-2010

The initial setup contains two scripts:

- `stored_procedure.sql`
- `stored_procedureV2.sql`

What I did is:

- Remove `stored_procedure.sql`
- Rename `stored_procedureV2.sql` to `stored_procedure.sql`

When I perform a schema compare in SSDT between a `.dacpac` not containing this change and my project the action it proposes is to just remove `stored_procedure.sql` and do nothing else, whilst it should remove `stored_procedureV2.sql` and update `stored_procedure.sql` to its new content.

As I assume this is where schema compare gets its information:

The `.sqlproj` of the source:

```
...
<Build Include="Scripts\stored_procedure.sql">
  <AnsiNulls>On</AnsiNulls>
  <QuotedIdentifier>On</QuotedIdentifier>
</Build>
<Build Include="Scripts\stored_procedureV2.sql">
  <AnsiNulls>On</AnsiNulls>
  <QuotedIdentifier>On</QuotedIdentifier>
</Build>
...
```

The `.sqlproj` of the target:

```
...
<Build Include="Scripts\stored_procedure.sql">
  <AnsiNulls>On</AnsiNulls>
  <QuotedIdentifier>On</QuotedIdentifier>
</Build>
...
```

Is this a known issue? Do I need to perform this in two steps? Is there a way to make SSDT behave the way I want?

Comment: I've run into similar problems. The way I would normally handle this scenario is copy the contents of v2 into the original SQL script, then delete v2 from within VS

Comment: @dartonw I did the exact same thing as you told but still get the same result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `stored_procedure.sql` still had `stored_procedureV2` as procedure name. Then SSDT actually does a correct compare by saying: `stored_procedureV2.sql` is unchanged and `stored_procedure.sql` is removed.

Comment: Are you saying it's fixed?